# Rendering <p:outputPanel> based on selected <h:selectOneRadio > option in JSF

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces

I have two panels:

```
<p:outputPanel id="contentDisplay">
<p:outputPanel id="dashboarddisplay">
```

I need to render either one of the `<p:outputPanel>` above by selecting the `<h:selectOneRadio>` button.

Here is the code that I have for `<h:selectOneRadio>`:

```
<h:selectOneRadio id="choice" style="width:100%"
                  value="#{Bean.selectedChoice}">
    <f:selectItem id="item1" itemLabel="Hours Allocation"   itemValue="1" />
    <f:selectItem id="item2" itemLabel="DashBoard" itemValue="2" /> 
    <p:ajax render="contentDisplay dashboarddisplay " execute="@this"
            update="contentDisplay dashboarddisplay" listener="#{cmpmBean.onChoiceSelect}" />    
</h:selectOneRadio>
```

How do I pass the selected value of the `<f:selectItem>` to the backing bean?

Though the ajax event is triggered I could not able to get the value for the variable "onChoiceSelect" in the backing bean.

Any suggestions will really helpful to resolve this  issue.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I'd do:

```
<p:outputPanel id="content">
    <p:outputPanel id="contentDisplay" rendered="#{Bean.selectedChoice eq 1}">
        ...A
    </p:outputPanel>
    <p:outputPanel id="dashboarddisplay" rendered="#{Bean.selectedChoice eq 2}">
        ...B
    </p:outputPanel>
</p:outputPanel>
<h:form>
    <h:selectOneRadio id="choice" style="width:100%"
                      value="#{Bean.selectedChoice}">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Hours Allocation" itemValue="1" />
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="DashBoard" itemValue="2" />  
        <p:ajax update=":content" />    
    </h:selectOneRadio>
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following code and it worked and  I could able to get the value in the backing bean.

```
<h:form>
                <h:panelGrid columns="3" cellpadding="2" style="width: 100%"
                    id="sysinfopan1">
                    <h:panelGroup>

                            <h:selectOneRadio id="choice" style="width:100%"
                                value="#{cmpmBean.selectedChoice}">
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Hours Allocation" itemValue="1" />
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="CMPM DashBoard" itemValue="2" />
                        <p:ajax  render="contentDisplay dashboarddisplay"  update=":contentDisplay :dashboarddisplay"  execute="@this"  listener="#{cmpmBean.onChoiceSelect}" />
                            </h:selectOneRadio>

                    </h:panelGroup>
                </h:panelGrid>  </h:form>
```

Both the outputpanel rendered correctly by selecting the either choices.